# ListView With custom Adapter setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-listview

I have looked at the other posts and I have custom adapters working in my app but this will not work for some reason.

I have 3 TextViews in the custom adapter and they are all set to:

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

final ListView VideoList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVideoList);     
VideoList.setItemsCanFocus(false);

VideoList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()      
{             
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) 
    {
        vibrator.vibrate(intVib);
        Log.i("test","VideoList onclick called");

        Object listItem = VideoList.getItemAtPosition(position); 
        String xList = listItem.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\n+", "");
        if(xList.toString().length() > 1)
        {
            String tvUrl = listItem.toString();
            Toast toastUDComplete = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tvUrl.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);toastUDComplete.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); toastUDComplete.show();
            //getVideo(v, tvUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast toastUDComplete = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Videos Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);toastUDComplete.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); toastUDComplete.show();      
        }                   
    }      
});
```

Comment: nothing happens when I tap a list item, at the very least it should vibrate

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328804/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-for-custom-listview-but-working-in) thread my problem solved when I return the value in getItem method

Answer (score 0):

If there is a checkbox in your adapter layout, set this property to it.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```